# Generation of entities with CodeFirst .net application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I am trying to generate a database on visual studio 2015 with "CODE FIRST"

I created a project with 3 library classes. In the domain library I created an entity named `Performance`:

```
namespace Imdb.Domain.Entities
{
   public class Performance
   { 
       public int PerformanceId { get; set; }
       [DataType(DataType.Date)] //f
       public DateTime Date { get; set; }
       [Range(0, double.MaxValue)] //g
       public Double Price { get; set; }
       [DataType(DataType.DateTime)] //h
       public TimeSpan StrartingTime { get; set; }
       public int NumberReservedSeats { get; set; }
       public Movie Movie { get; set; }
       public int MovieId { get; set; }
       public Theatre Theatre { get; set; }
       public int TheatreId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my context class in the data library:

```
public class IMDBContext : DbContext
{
    public IMDBContext() : base("IMDB")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<IMDBContext>(new IMDBContextInitializer());
    }

    public DbSet<Performance> Performances { get; set; } //4    
}
```

And I add this the `app.config` in the data library:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IMDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=IMDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have created the database, tested the connection and it's okay. But when I try to generate the entity I don't find any table in the database.

Comment: Have you used migrations?

Comment: is it necessary to use migrations to create the tables in the case when we created the database before writing the code of entities ?? or we just have to create the entities and then create the connection to the database???

Comment: you have to use migrations.. especially if the database was created before writing the code..

Comment: thank you ! i resolved the problem